# Drools - Is there a direct correlation between number of rules and permgen space?

Tags: java, drools, permgen

I ran drools decision table with 100 rules and it worked fine. But as soon as I increased the number of rules to 1000, I started getting permgen space error. I had  to increase permgen to 256MB for my process to accommodate the 3000 rules. My concern is as I keep adding the rules, I might need more and more permgen.

I am thinking of not using drools and develop a custom solution due to this issue.

Is this correct observation or am I doing something wrong causing the perm gen space requirement to increase

Answer (score 0):

From the below link it seems we can disable the permgenThreshold for Java 7 though it will negatively impact the rule evaluation performance.

https://issues.jboss.org/browse/DROOLS-1016?focusedCommentId=13144411&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-13144411

> The increased requirement in term of the occupied permgen space is not
>   caused by the new phreak algorithm, but mainly by the fact that in
>   drools 6 constraints are jitted, i.e. converted in bytecode and then
>   evaluated in compiled mode instead of keep using mvel for each
>   evaluation. You can have finer grained control over the permgen space
>   used by drools setting the "drools.permgenThreshold" system property.
>   This property represents the threshold of PermGen usage (in
>   percentage) above which the engine stops JITting constraints and let
>   them run in interpreted mode. In particular setting this property to 0
>   will completely turn off this optimization, but I don't suggest you to
>   do so because the performance gain derived from evaluating the
>   constraints in compiled mode is really relevant. My suggestion, at
>   least on the long term, is to migrate to JDK 8 that no longer has a
>   PermGen space separated from the normal heap space.

Answer (score 0):

Yes we are aware of this problem https://issues.jboss.org/browse/RHDM-488